# How to make multilined equations without using amsmath?

Tags: equations, amsmath, multline

I need to use `iopart.cls` class file in my document which cannot be used with `amsmath`. I need to write very long equations that span 2 to 4 lines.

Is there any way to do the same using `iopasm` package or other methods?

Answer (score 4):

The IOP guidelines

http://li.mit.edu/Archive/Activities/PubFormat/MSMSE/IOPLaTeXGuidelines.pdf

say to use the standard `eqnarray` (which does not require any additional package).

```
\begin{eqnarray}
zz &=& 1+2\\
   &=&  3
\end{eqnarray}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{rcl}
\sin^2x+\cos^2x&=&1\\
1&=&\sin^2x+\cos^2x\\
\sin^2x+\cos^2x&=&1
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: it is more normal to set displayed equations in displaystyle not textstyle math.